# Can I safely delete "VirtualBox Dropped Files"?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I use VirtualBox (host Win8, gues ubuntu 14). I want to free up disk space. I see that in ~/Documents I have a folder named "VirtualBox Dropped Files" that is taking 19.5 GB. Is it safe to delete these files or what are they for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `VirtualBox Settings > General > Advanced tab > Drag'n'Drop` is enabled it allows files to be copied by dragging and dropping from the host OS to a Linux guest (not vice versa though, still). The files end up in the *VirtualBox Dropped Files* folder, and if you have no further need for them you can go ahead and get rid of them.